# Fast method to transform a string with about 150mb

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I've been trying to decrease every single `char` value in a `std::stringstream` by `100`:

```
std::string str = stream.str();

auto decrement = [](char c) { return c - 100; };

std::string out;
out.reserve(str.size());
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(out), decrement);

stream = std::stringstream(out);
```

But it took **7 minutes** stuck on the `std::transform` instruction. That for a **150mb** text file.

I'm not using an optimized build. This is the debug build. The goal is to be able to have the code running faster for debugging purposes. Release results are secondary for this question.

Any suggestions on how to improve efficiency?

Comment: Any reasons for using the stringstreams? As your code doesn't really show the surrounding context and they usually involve quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: also, wouldn't reserving the necessary space in `out` beforehand improve performance a bit?

Comment: For one you can call reserve on `out` since you know exactly what the size is going to be (i.e the size of `str`) @dwcanillas beat me to it by 7 sec D:

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using `stringstream` to maintain compatibility with third party software. Will try that, @dwcanillas. Very well observed.

Comment: I just edited the code adding the `reserve` to `out`. Still no sensitive improvement.

Comment: I don't see a reason to read entire stream into string. Why don't you just read from stream, transform and write to output stream?

Comment: There must be something you haven't shown as I can't duplicate your results. For a 170MB text file the transform takes 3.3sec (2.7sec if I `reserve()`). Are you sure it is the transform portion taking the time and not the streaming in/out at the beginning and end?

Comment: @uesp as in Raphael's answer, the problem was probably the use of a different output string. Transforming "in place" took me about about 3 seconds.

Comment: Using an in place transform takes me 0.5sec compared to 3sec with your original code. A lot different than 420sec which seems odd.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino And even after you changed to "in-place", I doubt you were running an optimized build.  If so, then your original results are not relevant.

Comment: There are couple more things in your code: capture-by-value in a lambda, where you don't need any capture at all; and `return c -= 100;` instead of just `return c - 100;`.

Comment: Measuring (and comparing) running times without optimizations makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I was just having 7 minutes of load time. It didn't matter to me whether the debug was optimized or not. I was sure it would take too long on release too. Also, I needed the code to run faster even on debug because I could not afford waiting 7 minutes every time I would want to debug the solution.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino If you're using Visual Studio, the reason for the slow unoptimized code is that there are a **lot** of debugging checks, iterator validation, etc. that goes on when calling STL functions.  It makes absolutely no sense to post timings from such builds.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino `Also, I needed the code to run faster even on debug`  You could have just built a release version with debugging info.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, read my disclaimer on the question. I hope it makes things clear. Either way, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino Even with your disclaimer, you are changing your code to do something that you may not have wanted to have done.  You are artificially (if you want to call it that) changing your code to satisfy the quirks of running in debug.  That is a poor reason for making changes like that.  You should create a release build with debugging information included.  That is trivial to do in Visual Studio (if you're using that).  Then you would have no iterator checking and other "slow" functionality implemented.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I disagree: being able to work with your code base in debug is critical, and having everything be optimized (and harder to debug) just because one narrow bit is too slow in debug makes your debug build less useful.  Things being abysmally slow in debug is a serious problem.  But once things are "fast enough" to be runnable, getting the last little bit of speed (in debug) matters less than in release.

Comment: @Yakk That may be possible if the code to change is not dramatic.  But imagine if you're using, say a `std::map`, and you find out it is slow in debug.  Does that mean you dump using it and code a home-made, possibly buggy map, just to satisfy debug purposes?  And let's say that the `map` really outperformed the home-made replacement when run in release?  That's the danger of changing code just to satisfy debug requirements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, replacing `std::map` is a good step, for both debug and release purposes, as it is pretty slow.  ;)  But yes, if your code is undebugably slow, fixing it is worth a modest sacrifice, even if release is acceptably fast.  A modest release-time slowdown might even be worth it, because developer time can always be used to speed up release builds, and undebugable time wastes developer time.  If the release code is in a critical performance path, well, then you have a problem, as it needs to be fast in both.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One thing I'd consider would be transforming it in place if you don't use your `str` for anything else. That way you write back to the same location you read from and might get better caching behaviour. Simply change

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(out), decrement);
```

to

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), decrement);
```

and you can get rid of your `out` string completely. The 3rd (destination) parameter is allowed to be the same as the first parameter.

Not only does that get rid completely of the extra 150MB string variable, you previously had to access two different locations in the memory that should be quite a bit apart. With reading from and writing back to the same place you make sure that there really is maximum use of the cache.

Of course this mutates `str` so it's only really useful if you don't need the original `str` variable for something else.

End result:

```
std::string str = stream.str();

auto decrement = [](char c) { return c - 100; };
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), decrement);
stream = std::stringstream(str);
```

Comment: Editing in place sounds like a good try. Will give that a chance.

Comment: BOOM! Works perfectly. It took the code less than 3 seconds to run!!! And it feels so obvious now... I recommend editing and adding a further explanation on why it is better to change the string in place (avoid copying and all that stuff).

Comment: Even better would be to transform the data on its way into `stream`, _if_ that's possible here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit might be worth a seperate answer since it was already mentioned on the question comments already. I don't usually use stringstreams, but I think you'll need a second anyways? So not much potential between an extra string variable to work on and a extra stiringstream to operate on?

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl: It depends on his data flow. The data's got to get into the stream somehow, and it may be convenient to transform the characters on their way in in the first place: the transformation has been made since the very beginning of the stream's lifetime and you need no new strings or streams at all. But that may not fit his application; we just don't know.

Comment: nits: you don't have to capture anything in the lambda, just plain `[]` will do, and you also can return `c - 100` instead of `c -= 100`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two obvious speedups.

The first is to transform in-place.

```
std::string str = stream.str();

auto decrement = [=](char c) { return c -= 100; };

std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), decrement);

stream = std::stringstream(str);
```

which was covered by Raphael.

The second, which is only because you want DEBUG optimized speed, is to bypass possibly debug iterator checks.

```
std::string str = stream.str();

auto decrement = [=](char c) { return c -= 100; };

std::transform(&str[0], (&str[0])+str.size(), (&str[0]), decrement);

stream = std::stringstream(str);
```

here we replace `begin()` with `&str[0]`, a raw pointer to the character buffer contents.  If you are working with extremely strange `basic_string`s, use `std::addressof` instead of `&`.

In a system with a iterators encumbered with debugging instrumentation, this could be much faster.  In an optimized build, I would expect it to be the same speed.

Comment: C++11 guarantees that `data()` and `c_str()` return a pointer to the internal array used by `string`, so we can use either of these in place of `&str[0]`.

Comment: Ah, `data()` and `c_str()` return `const char*`, so we can only use them for specifying the input range.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly less elegant but I think still acceptable (also depends on your target machine) would be use of sse intrinsics (SSE2) if you need extra speed (around 5x faster than solution presented by Raphael).

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

__m128i dec = _mm_set1_epi8(100);
size_t x = 0;
for (; x < str.size()-15; x+=16)
{
    __m128i sse = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&str[x]);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&str[x], _mm_sub_epi8(sse, dec));
}

for (; x < str.size(); ++x)
    str[x] -= 100;
```

Comment: you might want an alignas(16) on that string buffer too, to be able to use the aligned version of the load. which probably would mean you'd have to allocate the array manually rather than using std::string (or use some other SIMD friendly container)

Comment: Interesting and useful but I don't need that much of increase in performance.